# Azure Functions - Dynamic blob container in Blob binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I need to add files to an Azure Storage Account using an Azure Function App with a Queuetrigger. But the container needs to be added dynamically. How is that possible?

```
        public static async Task Run(
            [QueueTrigger("activitylogevents", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] Log activitylogevents,
Dynamic ==> [Blob("{dynamicc container}/dev/bronze/logs.json", FileAccess.Read)] Stream streamIn,
            ILogger log)
        { ... Code doing stuff ... }
```

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic based on what? What determines the container name?

Comment: Is it possible to access the properties on the activitylogevents object comming in from the Queuetrigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `IBinder` to dynamically define your `BlobAttribute`:

```cs
public static void MyFunction1(
[QueueTrigger("activitylogevents", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] Log activitylogevents,
IBinder binderIn,
ILogger log)
{
    var blobInAttribute = new BlobAttribute(myUrl, FileAccess.Read) { Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting" };
    var streamIn = binderIn.Bind<Stream>(blobInAttribute);
    //other code
}
```